# Unreveal animation canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

Can anyone help me how to do the reverse the animation of this?

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
// shim layer with setTimeout fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();

var cvs = $('cvs');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
var x = 0, y = 0, r = 0, count = 0;

x = cvs.width / 2;
y = cvs.height / 2;
time = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(cvs.width, 2) + 
                 Math.pow(cvs.height, 2) ) / 2;

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.rect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
ctx.fill();
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";

(function animate() {
    if( count >= time ) {
        return false;
    }else {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        r++;
        count++;
        window.requestAnimFrame(animate, 0);
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j57msxr5/10/

I can't find a way to make the circle shrink. From big to small/dot/gone.

Comment: Fiddle with the radius. Start with `r=cvs.width/2` and try `r--` instead of `r++`.

Comment: been than that. Not happening.

Comment: You have to clear the canvas each step if you go backwards

Comment: clear it using ? ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height) ? nope, it gives me blank

Comment: can you provide me with a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a different approach. I'd start with objects that represent what's going to be drawn on canvas, and maintain the state within those objects. Then to stop the animation you can check if the radius is more than zero:

```
var $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);

var cvs = $('cvs');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

var circle = {
    x: cvs.height/2,
    y: cvs.width/2,
    radius: cvs.width/2,
    color: 'white',
    animate: function() {
        if (this.radius > 0) {
            this.radius--;
        }
        return this;
    },
    draw: function(ctx) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2*Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        return this;
    }
};

var bg = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: cvs.width,
    h: cvs.height,
    color: 'red',
    draw: function(ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        ctx.fill();
    }
};

(function frame() {
    // If you draw your objects in order
    // you don't need to set globalCompositeOperation
    bg.draw(ctx);
    circle.draw(ctx).animate();

    requestAnimationFrame(frame);   
}());
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9uLrL6d6/